# How to draw two group theory table in tikz

Tags: tables

I will be adding two tables in my beamer presentation. I want to draw the two tables given below.

```
\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } 

\hline

col1 & col2 & col3 \\

\hline

\multirow{3}{4em}{Multiple row} & cell2 & cell3 \\ 

& cell5 & cell6 \\ 

& cell8 & cell9 \\ 

\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{center}
```

There are two problems with the above table, first it is a closed box which I don't need(see the image below ) and second I want to put two tables together not one after another.

But I want tables in the format given below:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a) a compilable document and b) format your code in here with marking by mouse and pressing `CTRL-K` ...

Comment: what is the problem? just put your table into frame.

Comment: make two table without empty lines between them. provide complete small document (mwe), that we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Just the way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{ c| c c c c } 
  0? &$a_1$&$a_2$&\ldots&$a_n$\\\hline
  $a_n$&$a_1$&$a_2$&\ldots&$a_n-1$\\
  \vdots&&&&\\
  \\
\multicolumn{5}{c}{$H(0,1)$}
\end{tabular}\hspace{50pt}
\begin{tabular}{ c| c c c c } 
  0? &$a_1$&$a_2$&\ldots&$a_n$\\\hline
  $a_n$&$a_1$&$a_2$&\ldots&$a_n-1$\\
  \vdots&&&&\\
   \\
\multicolumn{5}{c}{$H(0,1)$}
\end{tabular}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

use [koleygr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/120578/koleygr) answer as you mwe (is it so difficult to provide?) and adopted my comment above to an answer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Group theory table}
\[
    \begin{array}{ c| c c c c }
    0   &   a_1 &   a_2 &   \ldots  &   a_n     \\
    \hline
    a_n &   a_1 &   a_2 &   \ldots  &   a_{n-1} \\
    \vdots  &   &       &           &           \\[3ex]
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{$H(0,1)$}
    \end{array}\qquad
    \begin{array}{ c| c c c c }
    0   &   a_1 &   a_2 &   \ldots  &   a_n     \\
    \hline
    a_n &   a_1 &   a_2 &   \ldots  &   a_{n-1} \\
    \vdots  &   &       &           &           \\[3ex]
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{$H(0,1)$}
    \end{array}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: result:]

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a crude attempt but is this sufficient?

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{c|cccccc|ccccc}
\circ & a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_n & \qquad & \circ & b_1 & b_2 & \cdots & b_n \\
\cline{1-5} \cline{7-11}
a_1 & a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_n & & b_1 & b_2 & b_2 & \cdots & b_n \\
a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & \cdots & a_{n-1} & & b_2 & b_2 & b_3 & \cdots & b_n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
a_n & a_4 & a_5 & \cdots & a_6 & & b_n & b_2 & b_3 & \cdots & b_5 \\
\multicolumn{11}{c}{} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{(G,\circ)} & & & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
& \multicolumn{2}{l}{(H,\circ)}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```